# Video.js changing source and seeking simultaneously

Tags: html5-video, video.js, seek

I am trying to build a site using video.js to view videos. We need to switch videos while maintaining the currentTime value from the old video. The way I have it working right now is using the loadedmetadata event to set currentTime. The problem I am seeing with this is that the first frame of the video gets shown momentarily while the player seeks to the right time. I am new to JS programming so perhaps I am doing something wrong but I do not see anything in the docs that can help me overcome this. I am trying to render H.264/mp4 videos in Chrome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the preload setting to 'metadata' might help this in the browsers that support that setting.

```
preload="metadata"
```

Then it supposedly should only load the metadata and trigger the loadedmetadata event, and not show the first frame. That is unless providing any new src forces preloading, and I'm not sure off the top of my head.

HTML5 video doesn't give us a lot of options around seamless switching videos unfortunately. The media source API proposal from Google/Microsoft/Netflix aims to fix this. http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

https://bitbucket.org/felixschwarz/videojs-hdtoggle/

As seen [here](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1671-changing-video-source) on the old videoJS-Forum I think you might have to declare `preload="auto"`.
In the linked forum-threat there are also some changes I made documented.